# Get Store ID by store code Magento 2

Tags: magento2, store-id, store-code

How to get **Store ID** by **store code** in Magento 2

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use below code :

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
$storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
$storecode = 'de'; //storecode here
    // get array of stores with storecode as key
    $stores = $storeManager->getStores(true, true);
    // check stores array for this storecode 
    if(isset($stores[$storecode]){
        $store_id = $stores[$storecode]->getId();
    }
echo $store_id;
```

Comment: Is the object manager recommend to use, is any best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 24):

You could use `Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface`.

In your constructor:

```
protected $storeRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
) {
    $this->storeRepository= $storeRepository;
}
```

From where you would like to get the store ID:

```
try {
    $store = $this->storeRepository->get('store_code');
    echo $store->getId(); // this is the store ID
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    // store not found
}
```

Comment: Way better than given answer. Single store is loaded instead of all of them. Also try/catch is used

Comment: I had to use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository` instead.

Comment: I know it's out of scope of the OP, but you can also call `->getById(2)` if you know the store ID and not the code.  This answer lead me in the right direction to solve my needs that way.  There also is `\Magento\Store\Api\WebsiteRepositoryInterface` that is similar but for the website scope.

Answer (score 3):

> Sometimes, during Magento 2 customization you need to get the store Information programmatically. You may need to get a current Store ID, Store Code, Name, Website ID, or current URL.

To retrieve this data use the singleton instance of the following class:

\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
For example, you can include it in your class constructor and then call:
You can define in separate function in helper and block and you can call it.
I have just given the idea so it is all in execute function.

```
class Example{
  private $storeManager;
public function __construct(
    ...        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;        
    ...
}
/**
 * Examples
 */
public function execute()
{
   /* Get Current Store ID */
   $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

   /* Get Current Store Code */
   $storeCode = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode();

   /* Get Current Store Name */
   $storeName = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getName();

   /* Get Current Store Status */
   $isActive = $this->storeManager->getStore()->isActive();

   /* Get Current Website ID */
   $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

   /* Get Current Website Name */
   $websiteName = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getName();

   /* Get Current URL */
   $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();

   /* Get Login Page URL */
   $loginPageUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/login');

   /* Get Code of Store With ID 2 */
   $secondStoreCode = $this->storeManager->getStore(2)->getCode();

    }
}
```

> Hope this helps you.

Comment: This answer only explains how to retrieve the current Store, but the question was to retrieve a different store by code.

Comment: This answer is not solving the problem

Comment: I am just adding the get Stores all current settings. if you want store code to there id please use $storeId = (int)$this->storeRepository->get($storeCode)->getId(); I am putting this comment when we started the stack :).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    ......................
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ....................
) {
    ....................
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...................
}   
public function execute()
{
    // get Currrent  store id
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $store_name = '';
    // get Current Store Name
    $stores_list = $this->_storeManager->getStores(true, true);
    foreach ($stores_list as $storekey => $storevalue) {
        if ($store == $storevalue->getId()) {
            $store_name = $storevalue->getName();
        }
    }
    echo "Store Name".$store_name;
}
```

you can also get all Details of Store

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

You can StoreRepository to get Store Id by Store code.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface 
 */
protected $storeRepository;

/**
 * constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
) {
    $this->storeRepository= $storeRepository;
}
```

Now you can use it to get store id.

```
$storeCode = "default";
$storeId = (int)$this->storeRepository->get($storeCode)->getId();
```